# How can i make a message pop up every 12 hrs?

Tags: c#

How can i make a message pop up every 12 hrs in c#?

I'm just using a message as an example, thanks.

Comment: You need add some details. Is this supposed to be a system message or from a running GUI application? When is the time interval supposed to start? Is it a fixed time (00:00 and 12:00 AM) or 12 hrs after startup?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Windows Task Scheduler.

There is a managed wrapper available at [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The same way you do everything else that runs once every x hours- you write a program that pops up the message and call it every x hours with the windows scheduled task system.

There is NO sense in keeping aprogram busy for 12 hoursj sut to do a short low resource activity once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

you should do a small windows application and put it on the server and assign a scheduled task for it so that it runs every 12 hours, usually this is the best practice for this

control panel --> scheduled tasks -- > create basic task

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now;
    public void ShowMessage()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now > targetDate)
        {
            targetDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
            MessageBox.Show("hello!");
        }
    }
```

You may set [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to call this method in some time interval

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use Thread.Sleep() for long term sleeps! The MSDN says explicitly that sleeps > some minutes-hours are very very imprecise. And they are the more imprecise the longer the sleep is.

The best solution is to use the Task Scheduler. If it should be platform independant you can use a loop that does 5 minute sleeps. But this will also be not very exact.

Answer (score 0):

In windows app create a notify Icon so a pop up message can be displayed and then use the timer control to check the time difference